# Argument of type x is not assignable to type x

Tags: typescript, discord.js

Code:

```
export async function guildRoleUpdate(client: IMClient, message: eris.Message, emoji: eris.Emoji, userId: string): Promise<void> {
  console.log(1);
  console.log(message.guildID);
  if (emoji.name != "" || !message.guildID) return;
  console.log(2);
  const giveaway = await client.prisma.giveaway.findFirst({ where: { finished: 0, messageId: message.id } }).catch((e) => client.logger.error(e));
```

Error:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Guild'
```

When hovering over `message.guildId` it gives:
`(property) Message<TextableChannel>.guildID: string`

Hey. Would somebody be able to explain what this means, and how you can go about fixing this error? The goal is for this code to find a member based on the current GUILD and userID. However, I cannot run it due to the error above.

Originally I was using message.guild. However, this is the wrong value. So i changed it to guildId and now I'm receiving this error.

Comment: It means you're trying to assign an object of type Guild to the primitive type string, which is not a conversion that can be done implicitly. It is hard to tell why with only the small snippet of code provided.

Comment: @Alex I have added more code above. Thanks for explaining the error a little more.